# How to "dereference" a string to a git sha1 hash?

Tags: git, reference, sha1, dereference

How do you get the sha1 hash for references like `HEAD`, `HEAD^^^`, `HEAD~8`?

I know I can hack up `git show` to get what I want, but it spits out a bunch of other stuff I don't want.  Eg.

```
git show HEAD^^ --pretty=format:%H | head -n1
```

What is a simpler command that is more direct to the intent of what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```